# Idris: How do I rewrite/solve using a 'with' block in a definition?

Tags: idris

When I load this file:

```
%default total

data Parity = Even | Odd

opposite: Parity -> Parity
opposite Even = Odd
opposite Odd  = Even

data PNat : Parity -> Type where
     PZ : PNat Even
     PS : PNat p -> PNat $ opposite p

nat2PNat : Nat -> (p ** PNat p)
nat2PNat Z    = (Even ** PZ)
nat2PNat (S x) with (nat2PNat x)
     | (p1 ** px) = (opposite(p1) ** (PS px))

nat2PNat_5 : nat2PNat 5 = (Odd ** PS (PS (PS (PS (PS PZ)))))
nat2PNat_5 = Refl

nat2PNat_S5 : nat2PNat (S 5) = (opposite (fst (nat2PNat 5)) ** (PS (snd (nat2PNat 5))))
nat2PNat_S5 = Refl

nat2PNat_Sn : (n : Nat) -> nat2PNat (S n) = (opposite (fst (nat2PNat n)) ** (PS (snd (nat2PNat n))))
nat2PNat_Sn n = ?rhs
```

I get:

```
- + Main.rhs [P]
 `--         n : Nat
     ---------------------------------------------------------
      Main.rhs : with block in Main.nat2PNat (nat2PNat n) n =
     (opposite (fst (nat2PNat n)) ** PS (snd (nat2PNat n)))
```

It's not obvious to me what I should do next.

If I invoke the "Make lemma" function (in Emacs), the result is something that is not valid Idris, ie:

```
rhs : (n : Nat) -> with block in Main.nat2PNat (nat2PNat n) n = (opposite (fst (nat2PNat n)) ** PS (snd (nat2PNat n)))
```

The examples with n = 5 shows that the thing I'm attempting to prove is plausibly correct.

(The motivation for this example is I want to define dependently-typed types for even and odd natural numbers, ie **PNat Even** and **PNat Odd**.)

Answer (score 3):

It's very close to the `nat2PNat` function you've defined earlier. Just pattern-match on `n` and add `with (nat2PNat n)` to the non-zero case:

```
nat2PNat_Sn : (n : Nat) -> nat2PNat (S n) = (opposite (fst (nat2PNat n)) ** (PS (snd (nat2PNat n))))
nat2PNat_Sn Z = Refl
nat2PNat_Sn (S n) with (nat2PNat n)
  nat2PNat_Sn (S n) | (p ** pn) = Refl
```

Comment: That does work for me. I found that the last `nat2PNat_Sn (S n)` is not necessary and can be left out. Also, I'm going to assume that the failure of "make lemma" to generate valid Idris code is a bug, and I will raise that as an issue on the Idris Github project and see what happens.

Comment: If you left out `nat2PNat_Sn (S n)` then `nat2PNat_Sn` will not be total, which is what you always want from proofs. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Anton, I do want my code to be total, but I have a '%total' at the top, which should already make it complain if any of my proofs is not total. My understanding is that you can write a rewritten version of the initial function expression to the left of the '|' if the match on the right of the '|' gives you additional information about that expression. But in this case it doesn't, so there's no benefit (ie we already know it's `nat2PNat_Sn (S n)`, and matching `(nat2PNat n)` to `(p ** pn)` doesn't give us any extra detail about what `nat2PNat_Sn (S n)` is).

Comment: Oh, you mean you wrote it like this `nat2PNat_Sn (S n) with (nat2PNat n) | (_ ** _) = Refl`. The way I wrote it was due to using the Emacs' `C-c C-w` shortcut (Add `with` block). Initially I thought you meant to get rid of the `S n` case completely.